# Mysql nested dropdown

Tags: mysql, joomla, components

In component-creator, i created 3 tables:

- **Manufactures**

  - Name (J_TEXT)
- **Models**

  - Model_name (J_TEXT)
  - Manufacture (**Foreign_KEY**) (**Table: Manufacture**)  (Field key: ID) 
    (Field Value: Name)
- **Cars**

  - Car_name (J_TEXT)
  - Manufacture (**Foreign_KEY**) (**Table: Manufacture**)  (Field key: ID) 
    (Field Value: Name)
  - Model (**Foreign_KEY**) (**Table: Model**)  (Field key: ID)  (Field Value:
    Model name)

---

Then In my component I created:

- Manufacture

  - BMW
  - HONDA
  - AUDI
- Model

  - 5 Series     (dropdown:  BMW)
  - 3 Series (dropdown:  BMW)
  - CRV (dropdown:  HONDA)
  - Accord  (dropdown:  HONDA)
  - Q5  (dropdown:  AUDI)
  - Q7  (dropdown:  AUDI)

Car-**Now the problem is here for example:**

- Name: 520
- Manufacture: BMW
- Model: dropdown is showing all models for all cars!!!!???????

It should be show only “5 series” and “3 series” which is for BMW...

[component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlpeY.jpg)